# Is there a PHP equivalent of JavaScript's Array.prototype.some() function

Tags: javascript, php, functional-programming

In JavaScript, we can do:

```
function isBiggerThan10(element, index, array) {
  return element > 10;
}
[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isBiggerThan10);  // false
[12, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isBiggerThan10); // true
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Is there a PHP equivalent of the some() function?

Comment: hm Looks like http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php could be of interest, except that it also returns the matching elements

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/any_all_on_iterable

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, there is no **short circuiting** equivalent in the PHP standard library. There are any number of non-short circuiting solutions, among which `array_reduce` would probably fit best:

```
var_dump(array_reduce([2, 5, 8, 1, 4], function ($isBigger, $num) {
    return $isBigger || $num > 10;
}));
```

It may be worth implementing your own `some`/`any`/`all` functions, or use a library which provides a collection of functional programming primitives like this, e.g. https://github.com/lstrojny/functional-php.

Comment: This will have pretty much the same performance as array_filter solutions (though it might to better on memory usage).

Comment: It's not exactly the same behavior of JS `Array.some()` because that one it stops on the first element which returns true, it doesn't continue with the rest ;)

Comment: `array_reduce([1, 2, 3], fn($isBigger, $num) => $isBigger || $num > 10);`
Can be used as a slightly more concise syntax from PHP 7.4 onwards.

Answer (score 41):

It is not included, but they are easily created. This uses the [SRFI-1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#any) names `any` and `every` but can be renamed `some` and `all`:

```
function array_any(array $array, callable $fn) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if($fn($value)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function array_every(array $array, callable $fn) {
    foreach ($array as $value) {
        if(!$fn($value)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Might be faster to have `function array_every($a, $c) {return array_filter($a, function ($b) use ($c) {return !$c($b);}) == $a;}`

Comment: @cwallenpoole I [benchmarked it (ish)](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4ad03353993273807ba6a04c06dfee7f8e39bb1b) and my version is on average 3.6x faster than `array_filter` and even if all calls return `true` and early exit is not the cause my version does on average 1.8x faster which I found surprising.

Comment: @Sylwester Fair enough.

Comment: @cwallenpoole how would parsing entire array be faster than a simple loop when you stop at first success?

Comment: @RoboRobok Well, it's been five years since I suggested that, so this is a guess. The big O would be the same, but you're right about the Big Omega and big Theta. I think the difference, here, is that it used to be that the `array_` functions were supposed to be faster than using a `foreach`. That might have been a 5.x thing, or just a rumor from days of yore.

Answer (score 3):

There's array_filter(), which returns a subset of the given array based on the return value of the given callback.  If the subset is empty then it would be the equivalent of Some() returning false, and if it's not empty then that would match Some() returning true.

```
$unfiltered = [1, 11, 2, 22, 3, 33, 4, 44, 5, 55];
$filtered = array_filter ($unfiltered, function ($elem){
    return $elem > 10;
});

print_r ($unfiltered);
print_r ($filtered);
var_dump (empty ($filtered));
```

This approach doesn't short-circuit, however, and the performance will be inversely proportional to the size of the array.  This shouldn't matter in the real world, though, because the array will still have to get pretty huge, or the array_filter gets called a lot of times before you'll notice an impact on performance.

If performance is paramount then you'll have to loop the array yourself and break out of the loop as soon as you find a match.

```
$biggerThanTen = false;
foreach ($unfiltered as $elem)
{
    if ($elem > 10)
    {
        $biggerThanTen = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function array_some(array $array, callable $callback) {

        $i = 0;
        $n = count($array);

        while($i<$n && !$callback($array[$i])) {
            $i++;
        }

        return $array[$i] ?? null;
}
```

The function returns null if no element is found that satisfies the condition of the "callback" function.

If it finds an element that satisfies the condition, it will return the first one it finds.

The "callback" function that is passed as a parameter must return true or false depending on whether or not the element satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Use array_filter and provide a callback. Wrap this in another function to count whether there are any results

```
function array_some(array $data, callable $callback) {
    $result = array_filter($data, $callback);
    return count($result) > 0;
}

$myarray = [2, 5, 8, 12, 4];
array_some($myarray, function($value) {
    return $value > 10;
}); // true
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought of this, but thought it might be a bit inefficient, since array_filter returns an array, which we immediately discard

Comment: It also doesn't short-circuit, which can be *very* inefficient.

Comment: This is the neatest solution as there isn't a native function that can do this. The only other way would be to iterate and check each value... break and return true at the earliest opportunity.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PHP function that works like the JavaScript [Array.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) function.

I believe the code is self-explanatory, but if you have any questions feel free to ask me.

```php
// JavaScript-like Array.some() function
$array_some = function($an_array, $callback_function) {
    $is_data_found = false;
    foreach ($an_array as $an_array_index => $array_item) {
        $is_data_found = $callback_function($array_item, $an_array_index, $an_array);
        if ($is_data_found) return $is_data_found;
    }
    return $is_data_found;
};
```

**Usage in an ordinary array:**

```php
$numbers = [12, 34, 27, 23, 65, 93, 36, 87, 4, 254];

$is_any_number_less_than500 = $array_some($numbers, fn($number) => $number < 500) === false ? 'false' : 'true';
echo("<pre>is any number < 500: $is_any_number_less_than500</pre><br />");
// is any number < 500: true

$is_any_number_more_than500 = $array_some($numbers, fn($number) => $number > 500) === false ? 'false' : 'true';
echo("<pre>is any number > 500: $is_any_number_more_than500</pre><br /><br />");
// is any number > 500: false
```

**Usage in an associative array:**
(JavaScript-like Array of Objects / JavaScript-like JSON)

```php
$products = [
    ['id' => 'id_1', 'price' => 30],
    ['id' => 'id_2', 'price' => 233],
    ['id' => 'id_3', 'price' => 5],
    ['id' => 'id_4', 'price' => 499]
];

$is_any_product_price_less_than500 = $array_some($products, fn($product) => @$product['price'] < 500) === false ? 'false' : 'true';
echo("<pre>is any product price < 500: $is_any_product_price_less_than500</pre><br />");
// is any product price < 500: true

$is_any_product_price_more_than500 = $array_some($products, fn($product) => @$product['price'] > 500) === false ? 'false' : 'true';
echo("<pre>is any product price > 500: $is_any_product_price_more_than500</pre><br /><br />");
// is any product price > 500: true
```

**Using OP data:**

```php
$is_any_number_bigger_than10 = $array_some([2, 5, 8, 1, 4], fn($number) => $number > 10) === false ? 'false' : 'true';
echo("<pre>is any number > 10: $is_any_number_bigger_than10</pre><br />");
// is any number > 10: false

$is_any_number_bigger_than10 = $array_some([12, 5, 8, 1, 4], fn($number) => $number > 10) === false ? 'false' : 'true';
echo("<pre>is any number > 10: $is_any_number_bigger_than10</pre><br /><br />");
// is any number > 10: true
```